# Array/Loop add how to use valuables outside of {} Powershell

Tags: arrays, loops, powershell

I am very new to programming,I have a code like this,

```
select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName  "Pay-As-You-Go"  

$Sqldatabaseserver=Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer

$ServerName=@($Sqldatabaseserver|select -ExpandProperty ServerName)

$ServerName


for($y = 0; $y -le $ServerName.Length -1; $y++){

$PayAsYouGoServerNames = $ServerName[$y]



Get-AzureSqlDatabase -ServerName $PayAsYouGoServerNames|select *,@{Name='ServerName';Expression={$PayAsYouGoServerNames}}
}
```

the output1 is

```
dog
cat
Bird

Id                                         : 1
Name                                       : Taro
ServerName                                 : dog
Id                                         : 2
Name                                       : Hello
ServerName                                 : dog
Id                                         : 3
Name                                       : World
ServerName                                 : Cat
Id                                         : 4
Name                                       : Hanako
ServerName                                 : Bird
Id                                         : 5
Name                                       : Yuto
ServerName                                 : Bird
```

When I changed to like this

```
select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName  "Pay-As-You-Go"  

    $Sqldatabaseserver=Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer

    $ServerName=@($Sqldatabaseserver|select -ExpandProperty ServerName)

    $ServerName


    for($y = 0; $y -le $ServerName.Length -1; $y++){

    $PayAsYouGoServerNames = $ServerName[$y]



    $s = Get-AzureSqlDatabase -ServerName $PayAsYouGoServerNames|select *,@{Name='ServerName';Expression={$PayAsYouGoServerNames}}
    }

$s
```

It shows

```
    Id                                         : 4
    Name                                       : Hanako
    ServerName                                 : Bird
    Id                                         : 5
    Name                                       : Yuto
    ServerName                                 : Bird
```

Which is only shows the last array element = Bird

I would like to use $s outside of {}, but I would like to show whole $s like output1

How can I fix this?

Thank you so much

Comment: You are accessing `$s` outside of the for loop (the `{}`) it is merely being reassigned as the for loop...well...loops - to get a complete ***list*** you should use an [arraylist](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692802.aspx)

Comment: before your loop define `$s = @()`, then use $s with a += to add to it `$s += Get-AzureSqlDatabase ...`